# Build a 3D array for 754 spectra

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

My problem is I have two arrays, one with my data (spectra), one is just filled up from 1 to 128 (1D arrays). I wonder how I can do to build a 3D array from these. I tried to use numpy.vstack but is seems that I have to precise in parameters the different arrays. I'm sure it's nothing complicated but I am a bit stuck right now. The idea is to build an array like this (and then to print the 3D curve) : [image: Wanted]

The goal is to have the right spectra when I move down the wavenumber. In 2D I have for instance :
[image: Spectra]

With the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_lon = 128
num_lat = 128

tmpfile = "180523_WT_striatum_#1.dat"

fileobj = open(tmpfile, mode='rb')
fileobj.seek(1020)
binvalues = array.array('f')
binvalues.read(fileobj, num_lon * num_lat)

data = np.array(binvalues)
data = np.reshape(data, (num_lat, num_lon))


L = [i for i in range(len(data))]


fileobj.close()
plt.plot(L,data[0])
plt.plot(L,data[1])
plt.show()
```

Do you guys have any lead ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

num_lon = 128
num_lat = 754

tmpfile = "180523_WT_striatum_#1.dat"

fileobj = open(tmpfile, mode='rb')
fileobj.seek(1020)
binvalues = array.array('f') # 'f' stands for float 4 bytes
                         # It would be 'd' for float 8 bytes size
binvalues.read(fileobj, 128 * 128 )

data = np.array(binvalues)

data = np.reshape(data, (128,128))


L = np.array([[i for i in range(128)]for j in range(754)])

fileobj.close()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for i in range(len(data)):
    ax.plot(L[i], data[i], i)
plt.show()
```

[image: 3D array]